# Spring Batch reader using generics

Tags: spring, generics, spring-batch, reader

I'm just new in the spring architecture and I am wondering if it is possible to use a generic T (o what you want) in an `ItemStreamReader`.

Something like this:

```
public class Reader implements ItemStreamReader<T extends SomeClass>{
    public T read() {
    .......
    }
    public void open() {
    .......
    }
    public void update() {
    .......
    }
    public void close() {
    .......
    }
}
```

So I pass to the reader various objects that extends `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
public class Reader<T extends SomeClass> implements ItemStreamReader<T>{
    public T read() {
    .......
    }
    public void open() {
    .......
    }
    public void update() {
    .......
    }
    public void close() {
    .......
    }
}
```

use it like:

```
Reader<SomeClass> reader = new Reader<>();
Reader<ExtendedFromSomeClass> reader2 = new Reader<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read first about java generics.

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#What is a parameterized (or generic) type?

But if you define your class

```
public class Reader implements ItemStreamReader<SomeClass>{
    public SomeClass read() {
    .......
    }
    public void open() {
    .......
    }
    public void update() {
    .......
    }
    public void close() {
    .......
    }
}
```

Your method can return any object that is Subclass of SomeClass.

For example

```
Reader a = new Reader();
Subclass b = (Subclass)a.read();
```

Comment: Mmm.. my goal was to avoid the casting.. working on that I saw the more than one generic was necessary to implement correctly the class. It become something like `public abstract class Reader<T extends XInterface<R>, R extends Y, S extends Z<S, R>> implements ItemStreamReader<T>` where XYZ are classes or interfaces. But thanks the guide was helpful!